# Different kinds of living water

Tags: halacha-theory

In terms of purification Halacha, what is living water? Is there a difference between groundwater and rainwater?

Answer (score -1):

In [Vayikra 15:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.15.13?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0), מים חיים is decribed as "running water".

> And when he that has an issue is cleansed of his issue; then he shall number to himself seven days for his cleansing, and wash his clothes, and bathe his flesh in running water, and he shall be clean.

Side note:

The Rambam, [Mishneh Torah, Hilchot Mikvaot, chapter 4](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1526068/jewish/Mikvaot-Chapter-4.htm) explains:

> According to Scriptural Law, it is permissible to immerse in any collected body of water, as implied by Leviticus 11:36: "a gathering of water," i.e., any gathering, provided it contains enough water for the entire body of a human being to immerse in it at one time. Our Sages measured this figure as a cubit by a cubit by a height of three cubits. This measure contains 40 se'ah of water. According to Scriptural Law, the water is acceptable whether drawn or not.

And:

> According to Rabbinic Law, water that is drawn is invalid for immersion. Moreover, if there was a body of water that was not drawn and three lugim of drawn water fell into it, the entire body of water is invalidated.
> Although the disqualification of drawn water is a Rabbinic decree, our Sages explained it based on an association found in a Biblical verse. Leviticus, op. cit., states: "Only a spring, a cistern, or a gathering of water shall be pure." Based on a comparison of the terms used in the verse, they explained: The water of "a spring" is not dependent on man's activity at all. The water of "a cistern" is entirely dependent on man's activity, for it contains drawn water entirely. Our Sages said: The "gathering of water" should not be entirely made up of drawn water like a cistern, nor need it come entirely from the hand of heaven. Instead, if it came into being partially through human effort, it is acceptable.

The [Chizkuni, Vayikra 15:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.15.13?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=Chizkuni&lang2=en) explains the difference between running water and water that is collected from rain:

> ורחץ בשרו במים חיים, “and he shall bathe his flesh in running water, [emanating from the earth, i.e. a spring; Ed.] The person suffering from such involuntary seminal emissions cannot merely immerse himself in a ritual bath, but requires “living water,” as opposed to stagnant water, such as a collection of rain water. On the other hand, his vessels, as well as a person suffering from the skin disease tzoraat, do not require spring water for their purification.

The [Shulchan Arukh (Yoreh De'ah 201:2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.201.2?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Ashlei_Ravrevei:_Shulchan_Aruch_Yoreh_Deah,_Lemberg,_1888&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states:

> Spring water purifies even when it is flowing. Rain water only purifies when in a still body, but when it is flowing, it is Biblically invalid, if it is detached from a spring. If the flowing water from a spring mixed with downflow which derives from rain, then the whole mixture has the status of the spring for all purposes. But if the downflow is greater than the spring flow, or similarly if rain water makes up the majority of the water in a river, they do not purify while flowing but only while still.

Comment: This isn't quite accurate. Living water is a higher level from spring water.

Comment: What then defines living water? The Chizkuni explains that it can be a spring...

Comment: See first chapter of mikvaot, 6 kinds of mikva